# virtual com port not working on Android

Tags: android, usb, virtual

We have an embedded hardware which have two virtual COM ports implemented over USB. On Windows OS we are able to detect and read/write properly these Virtual COM ports. we tested it using hyper terminal.
But when we use Android, it is able to open both the ports but read/write is working on one COM port. It is not working on second virtual COM port.

I am using https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial this code to probe virtual COM ports. 
It is a CDCSerial Device. 
I could see while debugging the two interfaces are detected and IN and OUT end points are claimed successfully for both the interfaces. But write is successful only on first interface, it is failing on second interface.
for second interface I found connection.bulkTransfer (UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer) is failing, it returns -1 and there is no way to find out why same code/configuration is working for first virtual COM port but not for second

[BELOW INTERFACE IS WORKING]
UsbInterface[mId=1,mClass=10,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mEndpoints=[Landroid.os.Parcelable;@41a7b9e0]  [THIS ONE IS WORKING]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=129,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=0]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=2,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=0]

[BELOW INTERFACE IS NOT WORKING]
UsbInterface[mId=3,mClass=10,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mEndpoints=[Landroid.os.Parcelable;@41a7bd10]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=132,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=0]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=5,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=0]

VID=1003 (0x3EB)
PID=9253 (0x2425)

has anyone tried working with multiple virtual COM ports on Android? any hint to debug would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue, one of the colleague helped in debugging the issue. A variable in UsbDeviceConnection.controltransfer call was hardcoded.

Issue location :
in file https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial/blob/master/usbserial/src/main/java/com/felhr/usbserial/CDCSerialDevice.java

in methods
setControlCommand and getLineCoding, call to connection.controlTransfer have 4th variable (int index) hardcoded to 0, which should change based on interface selected for data transfer

int response = connection.controlTransfer(CDC_REQTYPE_HOST2DEVICE, request, value,0, data, dataLength, USB_TIMEOUT);

int controlTransfer (int requestType, 
                int request, 
                int value, 
                int index, 
                byte[] buffer, 
                int length, 
                int timeout)

variable index should be 0 for data transfer at interface ID 1 and it should be 2 for data transfer at interface ID 3

Interface 0 = CDC Assoc interface for Bulk Interface 1

Interface 1 = CDC actual bulk interface (COM PORT 1 on PC)

Interface 2 CDC Assoc interface for Bulk Interface 3

Interface 3 = CDC actual bulk interface (COM PORT 2 on PC)

Now both the interfaces are working.